# Is it possible to rip thin strips of wood only using hand tools?

Tags: hand-tools, resawing

Say from a standard board 1 in x3 in x6 feet cut strips of 1/8 in thickness?

Comment: Anything is possible, it could be done with a hand saw but the quality is f the strips?? Build a fence for a skill saw, sure lots of ways it can be done but a end result or objective may help to know if it should be attempted.

Comment: I need to trim some windows, and I have decided to not purchase any potentially dangerous equipment.  Thanks.

Comment: The way to do it, is you need to have the hand saw perfectly sharpen and good hand/eye control.  Potentially dangerous is a matter of attention and control.  A hand saw/tool can be as dangerous as a power tool.

Comment: Once upon a time _everything_ was done with hand tools. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: A hardwood jig (guide) for a hand saw might work well. It partly depends on your tolerances and tools.

Comment: It might be possible to have the place you buy the wood from, to do it(lumber yard) for a small fee(if any).

Comment: Do you need to reduce a 1x3 by 1/8, or do you need 1/8 strips to add to something?

Comment: Does "find a place that sells veneer sheets" count? Because im assuming the question is a means to an end.

Comment: Well traditionally you would rip it down to something like 3/8" in a rough cut.... and then "joint" it to make one side straight... then "plane" the other side to make it 1/8".

Comment: Manu what equipment do you have? Just about any hand tool can be considered dangerous. There are ways to do everything by hand but possibly moving to SE woodworking would be a better fit.

Comment: Making such small strip is extremely difficult without power tools.  If you have the skill do this by hand, you probably already know the answer.

Comment: @QuocVu don't forget, there are centuries old pieces of furniture with some rather exquisite inlays and veneers. I'm not saying that making these was "easy", but it was rather common place and they were made _long_ before there were tools powered by anything beyond a water wheel. It certainly took years of experience, but it is doable.

Comment: Are these window jamb extensions? If so, I’d suggest installing them, then using a plane to bring them down to (or near) the adjacent wall level. This will be fiddly, so consider sanding as it gets close. This will allow test fit of the casing to find high spots.

Comment: What is the actual objective?  What does "only using hand tools" mean?  Is it a test of skill to do this completely freehand with only a panel saw?  Or is it ok to use specialized jigs and tools?   If you have a jig and a guide for the wood and for the saw,  ...  you are well on the way to using a table saw, just replace the motor with a crank.  Would that count?  People are suggesting ways to buy stock that is closer to your end product but there must be a reason you phrased your question the way you did. What is it?

Comment: @freeman I agree. Power tools only made things easier but certainly everything can be made by hand the old way.  What I meant was the nature of this question implies the op is probably not an advanced level woodworker thus a manual approach could be too hard to execute properly.

Comment: Actually, @QuocVu, depending on the tools available, it might be much more _difficult_ to do it with power tools than by hand. Also, the OP explicitly asks about hand tools.

Comment: @freeman it goes without saying you need the right tool in both cases.  I would use a reciprocating saw. Neither I would suggest using an axe for the manual approach.

Comment: i meant i would not use a reciprocating saw

Comment: I've got to say, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me (despite having given an answer). What is the problem you're trying to solve with these thin strips of wood? Maybe someone has a totally different way of going about it that will make your life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust your thinking.

You've noted that you're trying to make some trim pieces. I can't, for the life of me, envision what you need 1x1/8" trim for, but I'll assume you need it and that's the perfect size for what you're after. (Oh! You're making doll-houses or other scale models! Of course.)

**I'd suggest that you rip your wood in 1/4" wide strips, then plane to the final thickness.**

Even the highest quality hand-saws will leave a rough cut that won't be acceptable for finish trim work. By cutting to 1/4" thickness, your cutting will be easier to handle than it would be at 1/8" (though it will still require a level of precision that you'll likely only attain on the later strips after you've had some practice).

By planning ahead to plane it to the final thickness, the precision of your cuts won't matter nearly as much, and the planed surface will be much nicer than the rough-cut surface. Depending on the installation details, you can get away with only planing the visible side. You may need to give the hidden side a pass or two with the hand plane to get it smooth enough to sit nicely, then do all the finishing work on the visible side.

A properly sharpened and adjusted hand plane will give you paper thin shavings, somewhere on the order of 1/64", so you'll be able to sneak right up to your final thickness. I'd suggest popping over to [Woodworking.se](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com) for loads of info on sharpening and tuning the plane to get it to make these paper thin shavings.

Depending on how many pieces you need to make, I'd recommend a jig into which you can place the freshly cut pieces, with a stopper at one end to prevent it from moving, and sides to act as a depth-stop so you don't accidentally over plane and end up with something too thin.

Comment: *"Even the highest quality hand-saws will leave a rough cut that won't be acceptable for finish trim work"* Do you literally own no Japanese saws? ^_^ *"A properly sharpened and adjusted hand plane will give you paper thin shavings"* Yup. *"somewhere on the order of 1/64"..."* [Duuude.](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/12667/how-to-face-joint-board-longer-than-bench-by-hand/12669#12669) (3rd paragraph.)

Comment: This is absolutely the right approach (in outline) and not just for sawing by hand. Even using a bandsaw — THE tool for this — you wouldn't be sawing to final thickness, no matter how good the bandsaw, how wide the blade and how sharp it was. However given the lengths the OP wants I do think this is going to prove basically impossible (I don't know about you, but I'm fairly certain I couldn't do it repeatably..... and definitely not on SPF if that was what they intended to buy!). I think there's basically only one way to go here, and that's buying in 1/4" stock to plane to thickness.

Comment: Uh, no, I don't own any Japanese saws, @Graphus. I hope I don't have to turn in my Garage Shop Access Card now...

Comment: Yes I'm afraid you do. We'll begin the cancellation procedure now shall we? ^_^

Comment: Now jokes aside you *really* do want to try a Japanese-style saw at some point. There are some great low-cost ones available these days, directly from China or on Amazon if you prefer (or from Lidl or Aldi if you have either near you). As you might know, not everyone finds they get along with a pull saw but man, the cut quality can be *awesome*. I have a small kataba-style saw with two blades, 22TPI and 17TPI and even the coarse one (coarse hahaha) produces a surface so good you could almost use it as-is with zero sanding. With the 22TPI one the end grain looks almost polished... even on pine!

Comment: One of these days, @Graphus, one of these days... The shop is in an uninsulated/unheated garage, so the going has been a bit slow the last couple of months as the weather has been a bit _chilly_. I appreciate the input and will add that to the list of things to buy.

Comment: Yeah I feel you. I have essentially an unheated workshop too, so getting in there and getting anything meaningful done takes some gumption.... and that's with our low temps probably being a warm day by your winter standards!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, ripping 1" x 3" x 6' to 1/8" thickness would result in strips that are 1" x 1/8" x 6'. I think that will be very hard to do with hand tools.

My recommendation is start with 1/8" thick wood. Not a lot of choices, but at least some [available in 4' x 8' sheets](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Utility-Panel-Common-1-8-in-x-4-ft-x-8-ft-Actual-0-106-in-x-48-in-x-96-in-833096/100543684). Starting with that, you will be cutting something like 2' x 6' x 1/8". The cuts will now be 1" wide instead of 1/8" - much easier to handle. Each cut will be through 1/8" of wood instead of 1" - so it will be 8x as fast & easy - actually a **lot** easier - almost to the point of score & cut.

Comment: 1/8" plywood sheet can be had in 4x8 sheets. HD may be out because of COVID.

Comment: I need trim wood, like pine etc.  And I can't find anyone selling anything closer to the dimensions I need.  If you know it, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You may need to be a little more flexible on the dimensions. For example, in a quick search I could find wood molding in ~ 1-1/2" wide by 1/4" thick, so if you can handle 1/4" instead of 1/8" there are definitely more options.

Comment: This is a much easier approach.  But I have never seen 1/8 plywood.  The thinnest sheet i found is the underlayment which is slightly under 1/4"

Answer (score 0):

Guitar makers do this all the time, but they don't use a saw, generally. Create a jig that holds a chisel as a scraper, and then you pull the strips through it, narrowing the space *slightly* each time.

The idea is to saw oversized and then plane or scrape to thickness. The takeaway here is that 1/8inch strips are best thought of as "binding". And binding has traditionally been made with a scraper.

As for how to get the starter strip, that depends on the kind of wood. Again, guitar makers would probably be doing this with softwood, and the initial cut would just be careful successive cuts with a sharp knife along a scribed line.

Comment: Scraping to thickness in this sort of way is totally a thing, and many older jigs use a spokeshave blade (q.v. Robert Wearing's books). But getting the *starter strip* is the key difficulty if one is entirely reliant on hand tools.